# PostgreSQL pg_hba.conf file Changes on Restart

Tags: postgresql, tableau-api

I have a Tableau instance with an edited pg_hba.conf file. All runs fine until server or Tableau service restarts at which point the file goes back to its original state and I lose all my changes

Please can someone advise on how changes can be kept even if service or server restarts?

Thanks

Comment: Not answering your question obviously, but I feel obliged to point out that modifying the pg_hba.conf file is very much unsupported

Comment: Apparently amending the template file is what I need to do